# IList.Select() that returns an IList (without copying)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, collections

I have a method with an `IList<T>` parameter. It's `IList` and not `IEnumerable`, because the method needs quick random access and most entries will not be queried at all (the algorithm is similar to [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)), and IList seems to be the only suitable .NET interface for this.

```
public static int DoStuff<T>(System.Collections.Generic.IList<T> list)
{
  // ...
}
```

But now I have something like the following situation:

```
System.Tuple<int, int>[] originalList = { /* ... */ };
System.Collections.Generic.IList<int> list = originalList
    .Select(x => x.Item1)
    .ToList();
```

The required values are not directly in the list, but are members of the list items. The above LINQ code solves the issue, but there is a caveat: The whole list gets copied! I don't want that, because the list may be huge.

How do I perform such a selection without copying? Is there a way to do a `Select` on an IList that returns an IList rather than an IEnumerable?

Solutions I considered so far:

1. Pass a selector to `DoStuff` and let it do the selections on the fly.
2. Write a wrapper that takes an IList and a selector, implements IList, and does the selection whenever an item is queried.

I don't like (1), because it's not the job of `DoStuff` to do the selection. Right now, (2) would be my solution, but I'm wondering if there is a nicer way to do that, maybe even something built-in that I overlooked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's nothing within the framework that does this as far as I'm aware. Your second option seems sensible to me. You'll need to make it read-only, throwing appropriate exceptions for the mutating operations of `IList<T>`.

One alternative if you're using .NET 4+ would be to take [`IReadOnlyList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh192385) instead - that would be significantly simpler to implement, as it doesn't have all those members that you'd just be throwing exceptions from anyway. It would also *enforce* that your `DoStuff` method only used "read" operations at compile-time, rather than letting it try to mutate the list only to fail at execution time.

Sample implementation, *completely* untested:

```
public static class ListViewExtensions
{
    // Used to take advantage of type inference.
    public static ListView<TSource, TTarget> ToListView<TSource, TTarget>
        (this IList<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TTarget> selector)
    {
        return new ListView<TSource, TTarget>(source, selector);
    }
}

public sealed class ListView<TSource, TTarget> : IReadOnlyList<TTarget>
{
    // Or IReadOnlyList<TSource>... it's a shame that IList<T> doesn't
    // implement IReadOnlyList<T> :(
    private readonly IList<TSource> source;

    private readonly Func<TSource, TTarget> selector;

    public ListView(IList<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TTarget> selector)
    {
        // TODO: Nullity validation
        this.source = source;
        this.selector = selector;
    }

    public int Count { get { return source.Count; } }

    public TTarget this[int index]
    {
        get { return selector(source[index]); }
    }

    public IEnumerator<TTarget> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return source.Select(selector);
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```